# why QCPColorMap is not setting my value for QCPRange?

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

i have a problem with colormap sizing.
I set the maximum and minimum x sizes, but when the map is drawn, the right border of the map is larger than the maximum x size that I entered in the code:

```
qMap->data()->setRange(QCPRange(data->m_xmin, data->m_xmax), QCPRange(data->m_ymin, data->m_ymax));
```

Why is the value of my variable m _xmax equal to 3004.86, and the map shows a border greater than 3005, probably 3005.5?
Similarly with the left side.

[image: this is a picture for better understanding]

```
auto plot = ui->pCustomPlot;
QSize size = data->getSize();

plot->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag|QCP::iRangeZoom);


plot->clearPlottables();

QCPColorMap *qMap = new QCPColorMap(plot->xAxis, plot->yAxis);
qMap->data()->setSize(size.width(),size.height());

qMap->data()->setRange(QCPRange(data->m_xmin, data->m_xmax), QCPRange(data->m_ymin, data->m_ymax));

QVector<QVector<PointRS>> arr(data->getMatrix();



for (int i = 0; i < size.width(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size.height(); j++)
    {
        qMap->data()->setCell(i, j, arr[j][i].a);
    }
}

qMap->setGradient(QCPColorGradient::gpHot);
qMap->rescaleDataRange();

plot->xAxis->setLabel("x");

plot->yAxis->setLabel("y");


plot->rescaleAxes();

RescaleCustomPlot();

plot->replot();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [setTightBoundary](https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPColorMap.html#ad03221cc285e5f562a0b13d684b5576d)?

Comment: You can also create a new class, which inherits from AxisTicker, and overwrite the `getTickLabel` method...